# Aframe font font-size and font type

Tags: aframe

How can you change the fontsize of the a-font or change the font to Comfortaa or something?

I tried this so far:

`<a-text value="hey" font-size="1px"></a-text>`

I'm not sure if you even can change font-size.
For the font, I tried URL("urlFromGoogleFonts"), css version, and just a urlFromGoogleFonts. None of them work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out how to change font-size for anybody who sees this: Scale works. Its default is 1 1 1 but you can obviously change it.